# How to auto generate function docstring in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, docstring

I am using Jupyter and I was wondering if there is a way to auto generate doc string for a function?
Seems like PyCharm and Spyder has that functionality but I can't find one for Jupyter notebook.

I want to have something like this

```py
def func(foo,bar):
    """
    Parameters
    --------------
    foo : TYPE
        DESCRIPTION
    bar : TYPE
        DESCRIPTION

    Returns
    --------------
    TYPE
        DESCRIPTION
    """
    #dosomething
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to install `Jupyter Notebook` on **VS Code**
Then install extension `python Docstring`?

[**Python Docstring Generator**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring)

[image]

Comment: Well, the OP was specifically asking for a solution for Jupyter Notebook, and **NOT** for VS Code